# How to visualise the area between polar curves using filling option?

Tags: plotting, filling

```
PolarPlot[{theta, Exp[theta]}, {theta, 1, 1.2},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
]
```

Looked into the `filling` option but does not seem to be able to make it work in the case...

Trying to make a visual of this

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html), which let's us introduce a second variable that [lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)s between the expressions:

```
ParametricPlot[
  (w*θ + (1-w)*Exp[θ]){Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, 
  {θ, 1, 1.2}, 
  {w, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Axes -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 But to more closely represent just adding filling use `Show[
 ParametricPlot[(w*θ+ (1 - w)*Exp[θ]) {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 1, 1.2}, {w, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None], PolarPlot[{theta, Exp[theta]}, {theta, 1, 1.2}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html) and overlay it on your original plot using [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

```
Show[
     Region[ParametricRegion[(w*θ + (1 - w)* Exp[θ]) {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {{θ, 1, 1.2}, {w, 0, 1}}]]
     , PolarPlot[{θ, Exp[θ]}, {θ, 1, 1.2}, Frame ->True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 However the `Region` partially obscures the plot. Recommend that you reverse the order in the `Show`, i.e., `Show[Region[ParametricRegion[(w*θ + (1 - w)*Exp[θ]) {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {{θ, 1, 1.2}, {w, 0, 1}}], Frame -> True], PolarPlot[{θ, Exp[θ]}, {θ, 1, 1.2}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]`

Comment: ok, done, thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
plot = PolarPlot[{theta, Exp[theta]}, {theta, 1, 1.2}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions",PlotRange -> All];
{pts1, pts2} = Cases[plot, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
area = Polygon[Join[pts1, Reverse@pts2]];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Cyan, area}]]
area // Area
```

> `0.787193`

[image]

Comment: The original code similar with @kglr  `ParametricPlot[θ*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}*(1 - s) +    E^θ {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}*s, {θ, 1, 1.2}, {s,    0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Brown, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &},   Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], Green]}, {1,       Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], Red]}}}, BoundaryStyle -> None,   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: +1 However, the region partially obscures the original plot. Recommend that you reverse the order in `Show`, i.e., `Show[Graphics[{Cyan, area}, Frame -> True], plot]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks!